# What scripture speaks of filling a bag and "compressing" it?

Tags: bible, scriptures, reference-request

When you purchase a box of cereal or bag of potato chips at the store, you often come home to find that 2/3 of the container is filled with air. This is because although the container may be filled up during production, while the container is "in transit", all the contents are slowly settling to the bottom.

There is a scripture I'm looking for that makes a similar point. Speaking of God's generosity, makes an illustration of how not only does God fill your bag of wheat or grain to the brim, but he "pushes down" on the bag, compressing the contents, so he can fill it even more.

Can anyone recall which scripture I am referring to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you are referring to Luke 6:38

> Give, and it shall be given unto you; good measure, pressed down, and shaken together, and running over, shall men give into your bosom. For with the same measure that ye mete withal it shall be measured to you again. (KJV)

Comment: That's the one, and you were very quick to answer. Were you familiar with it, or are you just better at searching than me? ;)

Comment: I remembered the phrase "good measure, pressed down, and shaken together" but I had to search to find where that was at.

Comment: @IQAndreas: The Christian singing group "The Imperials" had a song with the words from Luke 6:38 in it. The song, I believe, was "Cast Your Bread Upon the Water."